# Media Player Error Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my Application I am using MediaPlayer to play livestream links.

Here is my code

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "",
              "Loading..", true);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run()
              {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run()
                  {
                      mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        try
                        {
                            mediaPlayer.reset();
                            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioUrl);
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            mediaPlayer.start();

                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            // TODO: handle exception


                        }
                                progress.dismiss();
                  }
                });
              }
            }).start();
```

The Following error is occurs

```
 I/MediaPlayer(23237): mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!
```

and on some of the links that I am trying to play

```
 MediaPlayer Error (-38,0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You get this error (`MediaPlayer Error (-38,0)`) when the `mediaPlayer` isn't ready to play the sound downloaded from the URL.

One workaround is to set a listener which will start the media player when it's ready.

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioUrl);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}
```

For the `I/MediaPlayer(23237): mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!`, you should check why `mContext` can be null. With the code you provided, it will be hard to help.

**EDIT:**

You can also use an anonymous class to implement this :

```
         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioUrl);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: Where should I place the 
"@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}"?

Comment: just after `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` or you can implement an anonymous class.